# UIScroll view current position in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

Suppose I have a scroll view in a view & a scroll view's size is 320 width, 2000 height.

When user scrolls & decelerating stops, I want to know where a scroll view has stopped?

i.e. at 300px or 400px or at 600px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scrollview.contentOffset.

Comment: I found it. So, I tried to close / delete this question but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

you can track that afeter scrolling, what is the coordinate of the origin, using the following two methods.
 This are two delegate methods conforms to your UIScrollView class.

-

```
 (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)newScrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation");
    CGPoint p = scrollView.contentOffset;


    int curr= floor(p.x/320);

    NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,curr=%d",p.x,p.y,curr);

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)newScrollView
{

    [self scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:newScrollView];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the scroll view is done scrolling, it fires off some events to its `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You can implement those methods in the delegate to find out the new `contentOffset` of your `UIScrollView`:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint contentOffset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out where any view is situated relative to its superview by looking at its frame rect.  What are you trying to do?